# Doubt on how a parabolic Dupin indicatrix can exsist

Tags: differential-geometry

> We will now provide a geometric proof of Euler’s Curvature Formula. Choose p to be the origin
> of the Cartesian (x, y, z) coordinates, and let the x and y axes be chosen to lie in the tangent plane
>
> Tp at p. Then locally the surface can be represented by an equation of the form$ z = f(x, y)$, such
> that $f(0, 0) = 0 $and$ \partial_x f = 0 = \partial_yf$ at the origin. Expanding $f(x, y) $into a Taylor series, we deduce
> that as x and y tend to zero,
> $z \approx  ax^2 + by^2 + cxy$. (10.3)
> Slicing through the surface with planes $z = const.= k$ parallel to $T_p$, and very close to it, therefore yields intersection curves whose equations (as k goes to zero) are quadratics, $ax^2 + by^2 +
> cxy \approx k$, and which are therefore (ultimately) conic sections.
>
> Figure [10.1] illustrates the fact that these conics are ellipses if $κ_1$ and $κ_2$ have the same sign,
> and that they are hyperbolas if $κ_1$ and $κ_2$ have opposite signs. In both cases, the conics have two
> perpendicular axes of symmetry that are independent of the height k of the slicing plane. This follows
> from the homogeneous quadratic nature of the equation. For example, quadrupling the height of
> the slice just doubles the size of the conic, without changing its shape:$ k → 4k$ and $(x, y) → (2x, 2y)$
> yield the same equation as before.
>
> The use of this conic to quantify the amount and type of bending of $S$ at $p$ goes back to
> Charles Dupin in 1813, and it is called the Dupin indicatrix in his honour. The point $p $itself is
> called elliptic, hyperbolic, or parabolic according to the type of the Dupin indicatrix at $p$.

Later on, Tristan Needham says to reorient the coordinate axes in the tanget plane such that the cross terms in the Taylor approximation of $z$ dies off giving:

$$ z \asymp ax^2 + by^2$$

But, how could the above equation represent a parabolic indicatrix? If I put $z= \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is very small:
$$ \epsilon = ax^2 +by^2$$

How could the above equation possibly represent a parabola?